# Sql Server If condition whit select

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

What's wrong with this?

```
  DECLARE @error int

  If (SELECT ID_Projet FROM tblProjet WHERE No_Projet=@no_Projet)> 0
     SET @error=1
  END IF
```

Comment: What is it supposed to do? Are you trying to test if there are `>0` matching rows or test whether the `ID_Projet` value is `>0`?

Comment: Are you getting an error? What is it?

Comment: are you trying to check number of rows returned or ID_Project is a field in the database?

Comment: Yes this is what I try Martin. Do you have a better solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `END IF` is incorrect.

Do it like this:

```
 DECLARE @error int

  If (SELECT ID_Projet FROM tblProjet WHERE No_Projet=@no_Projet)> 0
     SET @error=1
```

or this:

```
 DECLARE @error int

  If (SELECT ID_Projet FROM tblProjet WHERE No_Projet=@no_Projet)> 0
  Begin
     SET @error=1
  End
```

---

Check [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933214%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) for documentation.

---

If you're trying to see the number of rows with that restriction you should do it like this:

```
 DECLARE @error int

  If (SELECT count(ID_Projet) FROM tblProjet WHERE No_Projet=@no_Projet)> 0
  Begin
     SET @error=1
  End
```

Comment: +1 for correct answer and if I could another +1 for being faster at typing than me!

Comment: If you are only checking if the condition is met then it should use IF EXISTS as then the table scan only goes to the first match rather than a full table scan to count the records.

Answer (score 3):

END IF is not T-SQL syntax for conditional statements.

```
DECLARE @error int

IF (SELECT COUNT(ID_Projet) FROM tblProjet WHERE No_Projet=@no_Projet)> 0
  BEGIN
    SET @error=1
  END
```

EDIT:

Since this is only checking for at least one row you should use the EXISTS functionality rather than COUNT. This is much more efficient, if ID_Project is nullable you will need to add a further WHERE clause to the EXISTS Query to add "AND ID_Projet IS NOT NULL" since COUNT(NULL) = 0

```
DECLARE @error int

IF EXISTS(SELECT ID_Projet FROM tblProjet WHERE No_Projet=@no_Projet)
  BEGIN
    SET @error=1
  END
```